# Magento2: How to Modify DropDown Country options on the fly?

Tags: magento2, customer, billing, country-regions

I need to create a restriction for the 
Billing [Country_Id] options

Based on a new Config. Setting that Pairs a Customer-Segment with specific
Billing Country options.

I found:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php::process()

I tried Testing on this code directly before making a plugin to hook into it at line:

```
$elements = $this->convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert);
```

I then logged the results of `$elements` I can see the list in the log gets trimmed to only the options I need. (Yikes!)

However when it renders on the frontend (After cache/generated folder cleared) It does render the default options selected originally in admin panel country allowances and ignore all my changes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should modify **Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor::process($jsLayout)**. Create plugin for this and modify country list.

Here **getCountryOptions** method is responsible for creating list. Also, this is private scope so copy that into your plugin.

Comment: Totally appreciate your help while I learn my way up on the new m2 ways.

This worked partially, I can ow filter the countries I want to, however
the list gets reduced for both Shipping and Billing

I thought I could add an extra param to the array indicating when to render for one and when for the other, however, I havent found the code or way to identify the renderer for each of the dropdowns on the different sections.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Magento Dev Doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html),  you can update template for any field of checkout page by overriding that field template and layout files in your custom theme/module.

In your case, file to override is

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\billing-address\form.html

Comment: Awesome I'll try it and post results thanks